# What exceptions does feign.RetryableException wrap?

Tags: java, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign, feign

The documentation tells me that HTTP 503 responses are considered retryable, as are some exceptions.

From experience I know that feign.RetryableException wraps java.net.ConnectException, and the other j.n.SocketExceptions, but I can't see where this happens.

Are others like java.net.SocketTimeoutException wrapped by feign.RetryableException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Feign, `IOExceptions` are the only exceptions that are automatically wrapped.  If there are additional situations where you want to invoke Feign's retry capability, create an `ErrorDecoder` and return a `RetryableException`.  For examples, see the [Feign Documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#retry).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the code in `feign.SynchronousMethodHandler`:

```
try {
  response = client.execute(request, options);
} catch (IOException e) {
  if (logLevel != Logger.Level.NONE) {
    logger.logIOException(metadata.configKey(), logLevel, e, elapsedTime(start));
  }
  throw errorExecuting(request, e);
}


static FeignException errorExecuting(Request request, IOException cause) {
  return new RetryableException(
      format("%s executing %s %s", cause.getMessage(), request.httpMethod(), request.url()),
      request.httpMethod(),
      cause,
      null);
}
```

So if exception extends `IOException` then it will be wrapped.